# UPDATE Column values with Case and JOIN

Tags: join, update, sqlite, alter-table, case

I have 2 tables "a" and "b".

**Table "a"**

| property | element | ply | ..

**Table "b"**

| property | ply | material | ..

What I want to do is to add a column to the first table called "material" and provide values based on the following rule:

*if a.element < 300000 write 80000 else write the value you would get from joining tables "a" and "b" on (property and ply)*

What I wrote for the above is this:

```
ALTER TABLE a ADD COLUMN Material INTEGER
UPDATE a SET Material = CASE 
    WHEN a.Element <= 300000 
        THEN 80000 
    ELSE b.Material FROM 
        a JOIN b ON (a.PCOMP = b.PCOMP AND a.Ply= b.Ply) 
    END
```

> I am using SQLite 3.14.1

But this does not go through. Any ideas?

Comment: You should update the question with your database platform & version. UPDATE syntax varies slightly between RDBMSs.

Answer (score 1):

Your CASE is almost correct, but to be able to do a separate join, you have to use a subquery:

```
UPDATE a
SET Material = CASE 
                 WHEN Element <= 300000 
                 THEN 80000 
                 ELSE (SELECT b.Material
                       FROM b
                       WHERE a.PCOMP = b.PCOMP
                         AND a.Ply = b.Ply)
               END;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the  answer and comments. Do you think it is more time efficient than what I am currently doing?

Comment: Possibly; doing two update is likely to be slower. But you have to measure.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that I was simply missing some parenthesis but I reformulated and broke the problem down to two successive `UPDATE`s. The query was accepted. This is how it looks like now:

```
UPDATE a SET Material = (SELECT b.Material FROM b WHERE (a.PCOMP = b.PCOMP AND a.Ply = b.Ply))
```

and

```
UPDATE a SET Material = 80000 WHERE Element <= 300000
```

The logic is the following: set everything using the `JOIN` and at a later stage update the rows that have an `Element` value < 300000.

This is most likely far from the optimal solution but it does work.

For the record I am aware that one can combine the two update statements above into one but I tried and got the impression that it is slower. Does this make sense?..

Comment: You should probably use a `WHERE` clause to update based on element.

Comment: @AMtwo I already did; forgot to update it here. Still testing tbh.